# Good way to delete vertices from adjacency matrix

Tags: c, graph, adjacency-matrix

I'm writing a small graph library for an algorithm course I'm attending.

I've implemented the basic operations like initializing graph, adding an edge, adding a vertex and so on.

Now I should realize vertex deletion. At first it seemed simple, but I cannot find a good way to do it when the graph is represented by an adjacency matrix.

My idea is to have an array representing the active vertices in the matrix and resizing the array and the matrix periodically, so I wrote this sample program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define DIM 4

void DeactivateVertex( int *Vertices, int DeactivatedVertex, int DimSetVertices );
void PrintMatrix( int *Mat, int *Vertices, int NumVertici, int DimSetVertices);

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    int *Mat = malloc( DIM * DIM * sizeof(int) );
    int *Vertices = malloc(DIM * sizeof(int) );
    int *TempVertici = NULL;
    int *TempMat = NULL;

    int NumVertici = DIM;
    int DimSetVertices = DIM;

    srand(time(NULL));

    //Initialize matrix with values from 1 to NumVertici
    for( i = 0; i < NumVertici * NumVertici; i++ )
    {
        Mat[i] = i+1;
    }
    //Initialize vertices set
    for( i = 0; i < NumVertici; i++ )
    {
        Vertices[i] = i;
    }
    /*
     * Vertices 
     * _0_1_2_3_ 
     * |0_1_2_3|
     *
     * Mat
     *  _0_1_2_3_
     * 0|1 2 3 4 
     * 1|5 6 7 8 
     * 2|9 10 11 12 
     * 3|13 14 15 16 
     *
     *
     * */
    PrintMatrix( Mat, Vertices, NumVertici, DimSetVertices );

    // "Delete" vertices 1 and 2
    DeactivateVertex( Vertices, 2, DimSetVertices );
    NumVertici--;
    DeactivateVertex( Vertices, 1, DimSetVertices );
    NumVertici--;
    /*
     * Vertices 
     * _0_1_2_3_ 
     * |0_3_ _ |
     *
     * Mat
     *  _0_1_2_3_
     * 0|1 2 3 4 
     * 1|5 6 7 8 
     * 2|9 10 11 12 
     * 3|13 14 15 16 
     */
    PrintMatrix( Mat, Vertices, NumVertici, DimSetVertices );

    //Memory cleanup: this will be done periodically
    printf("Memory Cleanup\n");

    TempMat = malloc( NumVertici * NumVertici * sizeof(int) );
    for( i = 0; i < NumVertici; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < NumVertici; j++ )
        {
            TempMat[i * NumVertici + j] = Mat[ Vertices[i] * DimSetVertices + Vertices[j] ];
        }
    }
    free( Mat );
    Mat = TempMat;
    TempMat = NULL;

    TempVertici = realloc( Vertices, NumVertici * sizeof(int) );
    if( TempVertici != NULL )
    {
        Vertices = TempVertici;
    }
    for( i = 0; i < NumVertici; i++ )
    {
        Vertices[i] = i;
    }
    TempVertici = NULL;
    DimSetVertices = NumVertici;
    /*
     * Vertices 
     * _0_1_ 
     * |0_1_|
     *
     * Mat
     *  _0__1_
     * 0|1  4 
     * 1|13 16 
     */

    PrintMatrix( Mat, Vertices, NumVertici, DimSetVertices );

    free( Mat );
    free( Vertices );
    return 0;
}   /* main */
/**
 * Mat => Puntatore alla matrice di adiacenza
 * Vertices => Array contenente gli indici dei vertici "attivi"
 * NumVertici => Numero di vertici attivi
 * DimSetVertices => Dimensione iniziale dell'insieme dei vertici
 * */
void PrintMatrix( int *Mat, int *Vertices, int NumVertici, int DimSetVertices)
{
    int i, j;

    for( i = 0; i < NumVertici; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < NumVertici; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", Mat[ Vertices[i] * DimSetVertices + Vertices[j] ] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
}

void DeactivateVertex( int *Vertices, int DeactivatedVertex, int DimSetVertices )
{
    int i;
    printf("Delete vertex %d\n", DeactivatedVertex);
    for( i = DeactivatedVertex; i < DimSetVertices-1; i++ )
    {
        Vertices[i] = Vertices[i+1];
    }
}
```

Does this is a good idea? What can I do otherwise?
Thanks

Comment: Not answering your question, but perhaps you could pass `DimSetVertices`'s reference to `DeactivateVertex()` so that the variable reflects the updated adjacency matrix. That is, `void DeactivateVertex(..., int *DimSetVertices ) { ... *DimSetVertices--; }`

Comment: Sorry, but `DimSetVertices` must stay fixed until the memory cleanup, because I use it to locate the correct element in the matrix

Answer (score 0):

- swap the vertex to be deleted with
  the last vertex in the array.
- update matrix accoridingly.